# $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}} \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ represents a functor & a beautiful glueing story

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, representable-functor

Let $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}$  the affine plane and it is well known that

$\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}$ represents the contravariant functor $$\mathbb{A}^2: CRing^{op} \to Set, R \mapsto \{(r,s) \vert r,s \in R\}$$ because $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}= Spec \text{ }\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ and every map $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]\to R$ determines a pair $ (r,s) \in R^2$. therefore the antiequivalence of categories $Ring$ and $AffSch$ imples $$Hom_{CRing}(Spec(R),\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}) = Hom_{CRing}(\mathbb{Z}[X,Y] ,R) \cong \{(r,s) \in R^2\vert r,s \in R\}$$

Questions:

$Q_1$: How to verify that $\mathbb{A}^2$ can be extended to a contravariant functor $Sch/\mathbb{Z} \to Set, S \mapsto \{(r,s) \vert r,s \in  \mathcal{O}_X(X)\}$? heuristically I would try to reduce it to known affine case since I can always cover $S$ by affine schemes $U_i :=Spec(R_i)$, i.e. $S= \bigcup_i U_i$.this looks like a situation where the most books on ag finish the proof with the sentence that "everything glues nicely together".

And I would like to know if it is in this situation really so obvious? Namely I choose an arbitrary pair $(r,s) \in  \mathcal{O}_X(X)^2$. restricting it to $U_i$ gives compatible family $\{(r \vert _{U_i},s \vert _{U_i})_{U_i}\}$ and appying the *sheaf axiom* there is a bijection between pairs $(r,s) \in  \mathcal{O}_X(X)^2$ and compatible families $\{(r \vert _{U_i},s \vert _{U_i})_{U_i}\}$. these can be threated by the affine case and the conclusion is $\{(r,s) \vert r,s \in  \mathcal{O}_X(X)\} \cong \bigcup_iHom_{CRing}(Spec(R_i),\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}})/ \sim$ where "$\sim$" defines the compatibility relation. can I use now some nice property of $Hom$ to conclude that $$ Hom_{CRing}(S,\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}) \cong \bigcup_i Hom_{CRing}(Spec(R_i),\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}})/ \sim $$?

$Q_2$: If I remove the "point" $(0,0)$ from $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}}$ then I obtain a new scheme $Z:=\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{Z}} \backslash \{(0,0)\}$ that is *not* affine.

nevertheless I suppose that $Z$ represents also another interesting functor,  namely $$F: CRing^{op} \to Set, R \mapsto \{(r,s) \vert r,s \in R\ \text{ & } r \text{ or } s \in R^*\}$$ now the fundamental problem is that since $Z$ is not more affine I don't know if I can also use an argument as in $Q_1$ via sheaf axiom and glueing. is there another clever way to attack this  problem?

Comment: Careful! It's not at all clear that your $F$ is even a Zariski sheaf, let alone the functor of points of a scheme (in fact I believe it isn't a Zariski sheaf). I believe a definition that at least produces a Zariski sheaf is to send $R$ to the set of pairs $(r, s)$ such that $r$ and $s$ together generate the unit ideal.

Comment: As a sanity check, whatever "$\mathbb{A}^2$ minus the origin" is, it should inherit an action of $GL_2$, and your functor doesn't respect the obvious action of $GL_2$ whereas mine does.

Comment: More explicit: $\Bbb{Z}[x,y]\to \Bbb{Z}$ with $x\mapsto 2$ and $y\mapsto 3$ is an example which lies in $Hom(Spec(\Bbb{Z}),Z)$, but not in $F(\Bbb{Z})$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: yes I see the problem. a beginner question: when you talk about $GL_2$-action on $\mathbb{A}^2$ what kind of action do you mean explicitly? an action on "points" $\mathbb{A}^2(\mathbb{Z})$ explicitly relized by $(a,b)^T \mapsto G \cdot (a,b)^T$ with $G \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or an action on the scheme $\mathbb{A}^2$ itself in the sense that $GL_2$ acts on the coordinate ring aka global sections $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$? if you mean the second one how is this action defined?

Comment: @Tim: I mean the group scheme $GL_2$ acts on the scheme $\mathbb{A}^2$. The cleanest way to describe this action is via functor of points: over a commutative ring $R$ we have an action of $GL_2(R)$ on $\mathbb{A}^2(R) \cong R^2$ in the usual way, and this action is natural in $R$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:one more question on the philosophy behind the argument you used to make the "sanity check": in our case the hypothetical functor $F$ that I postulated - if it would exist - then it would as you said inherit the $GL_2$ action from $\mathbb{A}^2$. is there a general principle behind argument? concretly if $L $ is a subfunctor of a functor of points $ H:CRing \to Set$ in the sense that for all rings $R$ we obtain injection $L(R) \subset H(R)$ and a group functor $G$ acts on $H$ in the compatible way then  this action automatically is inherited by $L$ if it is

Comment: also a point functor? or is your argument more subtle? by intuition I suppose that this expectations on subfunctors might be in general too strong? or not? because in our case we have exactly this situation: we observe that by definition such $F$ would be a subfunctor of $\mathbb{A}^2$

Comment: The observation is just that the $GL_2$ action on $\mathbb{A}^2$ preserves the origin, so whatever "removing the origin" means, the result should also be acted on by $GL_2$.